# Asp.net 4.0 Routing , accessing querystring in Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-4.0, webforms, asp.net-routing

I have an existing Asp.net 4.0 web form application which has used Asp.net routing 4.0. Now, I have to add a route to my web form application. But i cant figure out how to access the querystring to my aspx page.

What i did is,

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Products","Products/","~/WebPages/Products.aspx?pid=4",false)
```

After adding that piece of code what i expected was that,
when i browse http:\localhost\mysite\Products i should be redirected to my Products.aspx page and there I should be able to access the Request.QueryString["pid"]. 
But I am not able to access the querystring.

I doubt whether this is allowed in Asp.net 4.0 Routing for Webforms. How can i fulfill my requirement?

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
 routes.MapPageRoute("ProductssRoute",
    "Products/{*queryvalues}", "~/Products.aspx",
    false,
    new RouteValueDictionary 
        { { "pid", @"\d{4}" }});
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.aspx

Comment: this will work only if when i browse http:\\localhost\Products\2